# API Rest en TomEE

Tags: java, restful, tomee

Estoy desarrollando una API Rest con Java, Jersey, Jackson, etc. Al momento de implementar en cualquier servidor todo funciona correctamente, pero al desplegar en TomEE (el cual es obligatorio) al momento de retornar datos en formato Json, éste crea tres atributos más por cada campo del json (chars, string y valueType). Por ejemplo, si quiero retornar un campo llamado status y otro mensaje, me lo retorna de la siguiente forma.

```
"status": {
        "chars": "OK",
        "string": "OK",
        "valueType": "STRING"
},
"mensaje": {
        "chars": "OK",
        "string": "OK",
        "valueType": "STRING"
 }
```

Con otros servidores me retorna correctamente el json, de la siguiente manera:

```
{
 "status": "OK",
 "mensaje": "OK"
}
```

Haciendo analisis del codigo me encuentro que este comportamiento solo pasa cuando en el response retorno un objeto de tipo javax.json.Json, con cualquier otra clase ésto no sucede, aquí un fragmento de código de ejemplo:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response ejemplo(){
     JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                 .add("status", "ERROR")
                 .add("mensaje", "No se encuentra el usuario.")
                 .build();
     return Response.ok().entity(jsonObject).build();
}
```

¿Alguien tiene idea del por qué sucede ésto en TomEE y como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que veo es que estás creando  la respuesta con objetos.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder() // se crea el objeto padre
                 .add("status", "ERROR") //Se le setea un objeto hijo creado aquí mismo
                 .add("mensaje", "No se encuentra el usuario.")// Aqui tambien se crea otro objeto hijo
                 .build();
```

La recomendación es que si usas un estatus y un mensaje en todas tus respuestas, crees un objeto llamado por ejemplo Respuesta

```
Class Respuesta{
 private String status;
 private String mensaje;
//Getter and Setter
}


@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response ejemplo(){
                 Respuesta respuesta = new Respuesta();
                 respuesta.setStatus("ERROR");
                 respuesta.setMensaje("No se encuentra el usuario.");

     return Response.ok().entity(respuesta).build();
}
```

Comment: Inicialmente gracias por responder. Esa es una posible solución, sin embargo me limita la cantidad de campos que puedo retornar. Otra solución práctica que encontré fue usar la clase JSONObject del paquete org.json, el cual me permite agregar la cantidad de campos que quiera y soluciona el problema propuesto. Muchas gracias!